# 1 row, 2 child divs. clicking a div would toggleclass the parent row - but not if the sibling is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs inside a row. when i click a div, i want to toggleClass "show" for the parent row. so far so good. but - i want that if the parent row already has a "show" class and the sibling div is pressed, the "show" class should stay and not toggle off.

Meaning:

1. i press the first div. the parent row gets a "show" class added to it.
2. i press the first div again. the parent row's "show" class is removed.
3. same for the second div.

but - if:

1. i press the first div. the parent row gets a "show" class added to it.
2. i now press the SECOND div. I want the parent row to still have the "show" class. i will be gone only if i press the second div again.

html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6"><p>whatever</p></div>
<div class="col-sm-6"><p>whatever</p></div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$(".col-sm-6").click( function() {
$(this).parent().toggleClass('show');
});
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want like this?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
  let oldElement;
  
  $(".col-sm-6").click(function()
  {
    let currentElement = $(this)[0];
    
    if (currentElement === oldElement)
    {
      $(oldElement).removeClass('selected');
      $(currentElement).parent().removeClass('show');
      currentElement = null;
    }
    else
    {
      $(oldElement).removeClass('selected');
      $(currentElement).addClass('selected');
      $(currentElement).parent().addClass('show');
    }
    
    oldElement= currentElement;
  });
});
```

```css
.row div { border: 1px solid transparent; }
.row.show .selected {  border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6"><p>whatever</p></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"><p>whatever</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasClass` to check if it has the class already before toggling.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $(".col-sm-6").click( function() {
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('show')) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('show');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. 
The problem is that the row is the parent of both divs. so if i clicked the first div once, the parent has "show" and i'm unable to toggle it by clicking the first div again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
  $('.col-sm-6').toggle(function() {
    $(this).closest(".row").addClass("show");
  }, function() {
    $(this).closest(".row").removeClass("show");

   });
```

but it just *almost* did it, because if i press the first div, then the second div twice, then the first div again - fail.